# C# progressbar IsIndeterminate while exectue a function

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I'd like to have a indeterminate progress bar going while I'm doing a function. The problem is that while the function is working the UI freeze until the end so I end up with:

```
void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
            scrape();
    });
}
```

The thing is that as for backgroundworker, my scrape function don't trigger. I put just the scrape(); onclick it work just fine. The scarpe is something like:

```
void scrape()
{
    string url = "www.site.com";
    var web = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = web.Load(url);

    foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='bio']")) 
    {   
        //scrape things
    }

    progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false;
}
```

The progress bar go in indeterminate but the scrape() don't trigger and the bar still in indeterminate state.
Any help?

Comment: What if you put a breakpoint on the call to scrape? Is it ever hit? Also you can do it like this: `Task.Factory.StartNew(scrape);`

Comment: You'll have to invoke any UI action from the `Task`. Something like `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false);`

Comment: *Don't* start a new Task, use `async/void` and `HtmlWeb.LoadAsync` to load data asynchronously. Anyway, you *can't* modify a UI control like a progress bar from another thread

Comment: He doesn't have to use async. It's perfectly fine to start a new task.

Comment: @Sinatr trying to modify the UI from inside a Task is bad design. Instead of trying to use InvokeAsync, the OP should make the modification outside the task. At least, the Progress<T> class should be used to report progress in a safe manner

Comment: @Sam no it isn't - a sync operation wrapped in a Task simply wastes a thread while waiting for the long running job to finish. `HtmlWeb` already has a real asynchronous method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please post this as an answer and link the msdn documentation on the subject

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, since when invoking to UI thread is a bad design? Or do you mean in this specific case? I don't really care about case, I just see an obvious to me error and point on it.

Comment: Before you go any further you should strongly consider using the MVVM pattern as you will not have to worry about invoking a delegate on the main thread to update the UI. No worry about the UI freezing when you click a button.  The UI is updated automagically.  2 interfaces you'll be working with are `INotifyPropertyChanged` to update your UI and `ICommand` to handle button clicks.

Comment: @JacobRoberts, how would MVVM pattern help to avoid invoking (at some point) from model running in another tread? `async` will do in elegant way, but `MVVM` and binding to properties which are updated in another thread (try `ObservableCollection`) - not really.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos IsIntermeidate is a DepedencyProperty, not allot of people realize this, but dp's propagate updates back to their specific Dispatcher. in this case the dispatcher associated with the UI thread.  
this ability is there do to DependecyObject's inheritance from DispatcherObject ,

Comment: @Sinatr have you ever implemented the MVVM pattern in a WPF app?  It avoids invoking at all points... at least from the coders view.  It may do joining, attaching or invoking behind the scenes but that isn't something we need to be concerned about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your probably getting an exception in the code that's running on the background thread.

either catch your exception by registering to 
[AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Or more specifically [UnobservedTaskException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception.aspx) which is like UnhandledException but specific to exceptions thrown from Tasks.

or make your method async and await the operation in a try catch clause :

```
async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true;
    try
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
           scrape();
        });
    }
    catch(AggregateException ae)
    {}
    finally
    {
         progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: that make sense thank you very much!

I still have a problem tho, the app now crach even if it seems to work well with "System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
" when I call onlick. I have to close the thread?

Comment: when debugging are you running with exceptions ? 
why aren't you falling on the line that actually throws this..

Comment: if fix it with this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => but yea this is pretty much what it helps me!

Answer (score 0):

You should make your scrape method async and then await it in the button1_click and keep the `progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false;` call in the button1_click method as you are not allowed to change that from another thread.

Comment: You're right about the `IsIndeterminate` part but his code should work using the `TaskFactory`.

Comment: Except that he is missing the await so it would be await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
            scrape();
    });

Answer (score 0):

You are calling assigning a property from another thread. WPF does things to prevent cross thread accesses like this to keep all the UI logic in the UI thread (the main thread). If you want, you can call a method from the UI thread using a Dispatcher. You can access the dispatcher from any control using `myControl.Dispatcher.Invoke(MyMethod)`.

It's also possible to check if you need to call a method from the dispatcher or not. Use `if (myControl.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())`. If this value is true, you are on the UI thread and you don't need to invoke from the dispatcher.